# How do I install YAWS/Erlang?

Tags: erlang, yaws

[Here](http://yaws.hyber.org/embed.yaws) I got small example how to run Yaws embedded, but how I need to install Yaws to get it worked?

Comment: I would suggest you to rephrase the title in "How to install Yaws?", given the question is not related to 'embedded'.

Comment: I will try all to be sure and then rename it. And i really have thought i need special installation for embedded case.

Comment: @Yola - It's fine to leave the name as it is, [embedding yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/embed.yaws) in another program is, as Roberto states, pretty standard stuff.  However, the [tag:embedded] tag refers to embedded systems like toasters and garage door openers, that is, *computer systems running on dedicated hardware for a specific purpose* per the tag wiki, not to embedding one program within another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty standard stuff. You can download the package from:

http://yaws.hyber.org/download/

Uncompress it and follow the instructions on the README file:

https://github.com/klacke/yaws/blob/467a675866f5d6b62e25be0b03e7023acc910fab/README

If you prefer, you can clone the repository from:

https://github.com/klacke/yaws

Comment: Sorry, it my first sources compilation in Ububntu, im new to linux. And i did following steps 1 - ./configure --prefix=/usr/local, 2 - make local_install. But second command gave me the error: epam.c:2:22: fatal error: pam_appl.h: No such file or directory

Comment: sudo aptitude install libpam0g-dev

Comment: Ok passed througth. But next appears)) - Yaws: Bad conf: "Can't find config file ". Do i need to create it manually? May be any link about it..

Comment: Ok, yaws worked as standalone app. Can get access from Firefox, now will try to launch as embedded app.

Comment: Ok, just copied yaws into my app dir end include yaws.hrl, then add path to lib. All worked out fine. Thanks.